# Compare date values between cells

Tags: excel, vba

- I'm trying to compare cell dates between two workbooks (the last cell in column A for wbkA, and cell A9 for wbkB).
- Display "good" if date for wbkB is = wbkA-1
- Format of cells containing date: 08/13/2019 00:00:00
- the script seems to find the date but I get a type mismatch error when it runs. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the scrip:

```
Sub CompareWorkbooks()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim dateA As String
Dim dateB As String


Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\2G.xlsx")
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("2G Data")

Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\2G Data Traffic.xlsx")
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

dateA = wbkA.Worksheets("2G Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
dateB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")

If dateB = dateA + 1 Then
MsgBox "good"
Else
MsgBox "badd"
Exit Sub

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: what line throws the error?

Comment: @MilesFett If dateB = dateA + 1 Then

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring dateA and dateB as strings and then trying to add a value to them and compare them, this won't work. Instead, try declaring them as dates:

```
Dim dateA As Date
Dim dateB As Date
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your dates as Date. Try using the DateAdd Function. Trying to Add `1` to a string or a date isn't going to find what you're looking for.

Here's an example:

```
Sub CompareWorkbooks()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim dateA As Date
Dim dateB As Date


Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\2G.xlsx")
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("2G Data")

Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\2G Data Traffic.xlsx")
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

dateA = wbkA.Worksheets("2G Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
dateB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")

    If dateB = DateAdd("d", 1, dateA) Then
        MsgBox "good"
    Else
        MsgBox "badd"
        Exit Sub

    End If


End Sub
```